# Obtain adjusted means - Weight? Standardize? Use LSmeans?

Tags: probability, paired-comparisons, weighted-mean, lsmeans

I'm attempting to compare means from one year to another (and between groups at the same time point) by calculating adjusted values.

I'm not sure what method to use. I've thought about the following:

- Standardized means. Can means be standardized?
- Adjusted means: would LS means (e.g the "effects"package) be an appropriate method?
- Weigted means: can weighting be done for age and sex and what method would you prefer in R?

I have searched the web and this community; all options (except from the first one) appears to be possible, but details were lacking.

To clarify, I'm not aiming to compare the means (which could be done by significance testing, such as ANOVA); I need to estimate adjusted means (i.e obtain an adjusted value for each group).

Thanks for advice on this

Comment: Btw, I wouldn't say `probability` is an appropriate tag here. There is e.g. `paired-comparisons` tag that seems more on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

What would you say about [weighting them by errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) or [variances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test)? For comparing means within and between groups you can just use [ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) and post-hoc tests with age and sex as independent variables. Those are the "classic" tools for this kind of analysis.

Comment: My apologies, Tim, for being unclear in the question. I've edited it now. Cheers